# How to make FlowDocumentPageViewer editable?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to figure out the best way to proceed about paging my text in my UI so that viewer performance does not get impacted while at the same to making sure it is editable.

I have tried using the WPF RichTextBox control which allows for editing but when posting text with length above a certain amount you lose viewing performance and it drags. I also tried using the FlowDocumentPageViewer which gives me the visual performance I want but without the editing.

I want to be able to edit while maintaining visual performance with large quantities of text data posted to my UI. Can a FlowDocumentPageViewer provide that in someway? Or is there another?